# How do I find stars within milky way using galactic latitude and longitude

Tags: star, milky-way, galactic-center

I have data that contains galactic latitude and longitude of stars. I have to determine all the stars that are within our milky way. How do I find it?

Comment: Do you also have distance-from-Earth data for all of these stars?  If so, and the distance is less than a few dozen thousand light-years,  I suspect the answer is "all of them are in the Milky Way"

Comment: Milky way can mean two things. One is the name of our galaxy, the second is a band of light in the sky. By "within our milky way" do you mean "in our galaxy" or "positioned in the band of light."

Answer (score 1):

Stars beyond our own galaxy and its immediate neighbors are indistinct without a large telescope, so I assume the question is about the band across the sky, rich with faint stars.

The Milky Way's boundary is fuzzy, so its extent is expressed in terms of isophotes: lines of constant brightness per unit solid angle (e.g. square degree).
It is wider near the central bulge (galactic longitudes around 0° or 360°) than away from it (around 180°).
Most stars within galactic latitudes ±10° are in the Milky Way; most outside ±15° are not.
At galactic latitudes in between, galactic longitude and the choice of isophote determine whether a star is in or out.